# Creating a view that calculates percentages

Tags: postgresql, performance, view, query-performance

I have this table getting populated with top10 destination ports every ten minutes along with a "total" entry that records the total number of bytes and packets transmitted for each port for the time range.

Following is the sample table:

```
SELECT * FROM topdestport WHERE timestamp > 1569026690;  

  id   | timestamp  |    agentid     | destport | totalbytes | totalpkts
-------+------------+----------------+----------+------------+-----------
 17783 | 1569026693 | 192.168.5.38   | 1194     |   79115496 |    180719
 17790 | 1569026693 | 192.168.5.38   | 161      |    6138371 |     31449
 17785 | 1569026693 | 192.168.5.38   | 16100    |   18182357 |    111251
 17788 | 1569026693 | 192.168.5.38   | 20946    |    8235024 |     36704
 17789 | 1569026693 | 192.168.5.38   | 39885    |    7253228 |     16796
 17784 | 1569026693 | 192.168.5.38   | 443      |   32862884 |    129279
 17787 | 1569026693 | 192.168.5.38   | 50914    |    8586242 |     38459
 17792 | 1569026693 | 192.168.5.38   | 514      |    3911742 |     15096
 17786 | 1569026693 | 192.168.5.38   | 8        |    9380959 |     86096
 17791 | 1569026693 | 192.168.5.38   | 9991     |    4196072 |      4432
 17793 | 1569026693 | 192.168.5.38   | total    |  411467748 |   1057104
 17797 | 1569026693 | 198.211.162.66 | 135      |    1065921 |     61472
 17800 | 1569026693 | 198.211.162.66 | 161      |     864736 |      8949
 17799 | 1569026693 | 198.211.162.66 | 28909    |     896027 |       612
 17796 | 1569026693 | 198.211.162.66 | 443      |    1829175 |      5763
 17803 | 1569026693 | 198.211.162.66 | 49154    |     540961 |      2117
 17794 | 1569026693 | 198.211.162.66 | 63028    |   29299322 |     20209
 17798 | 1569026693 | 198.211.162.66 | 65223    |     896128 |       613
 17795 | 1569026693 | 198.211.162.66 | 8        |    3871066 |     67627
 17801 | 1569026693 | 198.211.162.66 | 80       |     779706 |     13515
 17802 | 1569026693 | 198.211.162.66 | 9605     |     732976 |      7853
 17804 | 1569026693 | 198.211.162.66 | total    |   52337162 |    239945
 17805 | 1569027293 | 192.168.5.38   | 1194     |   64900551 |    132184
 17812 | 1569027293 | 192.168.5.38   | 161      |    4837816 |     33042
 17807 | 1569027293 | 192.168.5.38   | 16100    |    9894703 |     64514
 17814 | 1569027293 | 192.168.5.38   | 20946    |    3625487 |     18181
 17806 | 1569027293 | 192.168.5.38   | 443      |   22534140 |     90898
 17809 | 1569027293 | 192.168.5.38   | 50914    |    6503324 |     28394
 17813 | 1569027293 | 192.168.5.38   | 514      |    4062611 |     12100
 17808 | 1569027293 | 192.168.5.38   | 53271    |    7676109 |      8518
 17811 | 1569027293 | 192.168.5.38   | 60056    |    4866841 |     29548
 17810 | 1569027293 | 192.168.5.38   | 8        |    6373754 |     54248
 17815 | 1569027293 | 192.168.5.38   | total    |  288440521 |    737546
 17818 | 1569027293 | 198.211.162.66 | 135      |     680178 |      3413
 17817 | 1569027293 | 198.211.162.66 | 161      |     801128 |      5784
 17816 | 1569027293 | 198.211.162.66 | 443      |    1123139 |      3567
 17825 | 1569027293 | 198.211.162.66 | 445      |     178228 |       941
 17821 | 1569027293 | 198.211.162.66 | 48447    |     273634 |       520
 17820 | 1569027293 | 198.211.162.66 | 49154    |     290261 |       963
 17819 | 1569027293 | 198.211.162.66 | 49155    |     344997 |      1167
 17822 | 1569027293 | 198.211.162.66 | 53       |     222161 |      2019
 17823 | 1569027293 | 198.211.162.66 | 56713    |     190333 |         1
 17824 | 1569027293 | 198.211.162.66 | 80       |     184392 |      1961
 17826 | 1569027293 | 198.211.162.66 | total    |   10320551 |     50808
 17827 | 1569027893 | 192.168.5.38   | 1194     |   65364115 |    140788
 17834 | 1569027893 | 192.168.5.38   | 161      |    4555358 |     24267
 17829 | 1569027893 | 192.168.5.38   | 16100    |   14795520 |     91161
 17835 | 1569027893 | 192.168.5.38   | 20946    |    4520208 |     22759
 17832 | 1569027893 | 192.168.5.38   | 33319    |    7210596 |      8344
 17828 | 1569027893 | 192.168.5.38   | 443      |   23856143 |     95467
 17833 | 1569027893 | 192.168.5.38   | 50914    |    6604621 |     28643
 17830 | 1569027893 | 192.168.5.38   | 60056    |    8208623 |     31333
 17831 | 1569027893 | 192.168.5.38   | 8        |    7966467 |     63532
 17836 | 1569027893 | 192.168.5.38   | 9991     |    3950939 |      3959
 17837 | 1569027893 | 192.168.5.38   | total    |  336832333 |    840397
 17844 | 1569027893 | 198.211.162.66 | 135      |     793398 |      4144
 17841 | 1569027893 | 198.211.162.66 | 161      |     870284 |      7162
 17839 | 1569027893 | 198.211.162.66 | 3422     |    2274015 |      1573
 17842 | 1569027893 | 198.211.162.66 | 43965    |     830536 |      9596
 17840 | 1569027893 | 198.211.162.66 | 443      |    1085678 |      4203
 17847 | 1569027893 | 198.211.162.66 | 445      |     350938 |      1815
 17845 | 1569027893 | 198.211.162.66 | 4459     |     733168 |      7856
 17846 | 1569027893 | 198.211.162.66 | 49155    |     441978 |      1615
 17838 | 1569027893 | 198.211.162.66 | 8        |    7568689 |     57893
 17843 | 1569027893 | 198.211.162.66 | 80       |     821480 |      3024
 17848 | 1569027893 | 198.211.162.66 | total    |   25117950 |    139873
```

I would like to create a view that I can use to gather the following data just by pushing a time range:

```
timestamp
agentid
destport
totalbytes
totalpkts
totalbytes(%) >> calculated based on total bytes
totalpkts(%) >> calculated based on total packets
```

Is this possible to achieve with views

Comment: Why can't you do this with a `SELECT`?

Comment: percentage of total, or percentage of top ten?

Comment: percentage of total.

Comment: The question should disclose your Postgres version, table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement showing data types and constraints), cardinality, what you tried (even if it's not working) and the desired result matching the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW topdestportView    
SELECT
  t1.timestamp,
  t1.agentid,
  t1.totalbytes,
  t1.totalpkts,
  t1.totalbytes / (SELECT sum(totalbytes) FROM topdestport t2 WHERE t2.timestamp=t1.timestamp) as perctotalbytes,
  t1.totalpkts / (SELECT sum(totalpkts) FROM topdestport t2 WHERE t2.timestamp=t1.timestamp) as perctotalpkts
FROM topdestport t1
WHERE t1.timestamp > (SELECT MAX(timestamp) - 10000 FROM topdestport)
```

- The value '10000' (last line) of query should be chosen to get the correct `time range` result from your table.

After this a `SELECT * FROM topdestportView` should return the results of this query.

Comment: Thank you Luuk. Can I change the last WHERE clause to be WHERE t1.timestamp BETWEEN XXX AND YYYY

That’s how I was planning on using it on my BI tool. The expected result is to see different percentage values for different time range selections.

Comment: Of course, you can, as long as YOU are satisfied with the output! 

Comment: database=> CREATE VIEW topdestportView AS (SELECT t1.timestamp,t1.agentid,t1.totalbytes,t1.totalpkts,t1.totalbytes/(SELECT sum(totalbytes) FROM topdestport t2 on t2.timestamp=t1.timestamp),t1.totalpkts/(SELECT sum(totalpkts) FROM topdestport t2 on t2.timestamp=t1.timestamp) FROM topdestport t1 WHERE t1.timestamp > (SELECT MAX(timestamp) - 10000 FROM topdestport));

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "on"
LINE 1: ...bytes/(SELECT sum(totalbytes) FROM topdestport t2 on t2.time...
It is complaining about the ON statement. Is this syntax supposed to work for psql?

Comment: I did not test good enough, I should have requested a DM to create `topdestport`, with some data, to have an opportunity to test...   I did correct two errors in my answer.

Comment: thanks. now it works but I was wondering if this is actually calculating the individual percentage of each entry compare to the total of all "total" labeled rows across the given time. When I add up all calculated percentages except the "total" lines in return it is more than 1000%.

Comment: This part in the query ` WHERE t2.timestamp=t1.timestamp` determines which values are used to calculate the percantage

Comment: ok. somehow the calculation does not add up. I am trying to get the percentage for individual rows based on sum(total) across the time range picked.

Comment: Ok, you will get it, once you 'understand' hoe this query works. It' not that hard, think it over, and if you are still confused, ask a new question. 